# Facing issue while reindexing document using elasticsearch-7.9.0.jar to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using Elasticsearch 7.9.0 having single node cluster. We have developed a plugin which is sitting inside plugins folder of Elasticsearch. We are using Elasticsearch SDK (org.Elasticsearch:Elasticsearch:7.9.0) and mustache client (org.Elasticsearch.plugin:lang-mustache-client:7.9.0) and couple of other jars. We have exposed couple of REST endpoints which our client services will consume instead of standard Elasticsearch URLs in order to perform CRUD operations on documents.

We observed when we try to re-index the documents, often certain fields of the documents are not getting updated. This behavior is not at all consistent; completely random in nature. We are really not sure which field will be updated and which wont. This issue doesn't happen for all the documents of the particular index in a consistent manner. We really don't know which document will have this issue.

Few important code snippets for reindexing the document along with log statement as below;

```
org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateRequestBuilder updateRequestBuilder = ((Client) client.getClient()).prepareUpdate();

updateRequestBuilder.setDocAsUpsert(true); 

updateRequestBuilder.setRetryOnConflict(1);

UpdateResponse updateResponse = updateRequestBuilder.get();

logger.info("Response after updating the document: {} " , updateResponse);
```

Sample response after updating the document as below:

UpdateResponse[index=sanity_616d2c81737fc26067d9d220_transaction,type=_doc,id=STZ_8411,version=39,seqNo=3955,primaryTerm=6,result=updated,shards=ShardInfo{total=2, successful=1, failures=}]

When we identify the document is not updated properly in Elasticsearch and introspect the log; we usually observe the log as above. Here the log always return the **result=updated** and **successful=1** despite certain fields are not getting updated.

Please note, this issue is not consistent. The happens very randomly.

Kindly help us on this!

Comment: Does it get indexed properly if you send the same document again?

Comment: Yes it does index properly, when we try to re-index the same document.

Comment: Hmm I have never seen such behavior. Did you try it with `insert`, would it be the same? Also, are you 100% sure you're sending correct updated values? I'd log the payload before sending to ES and make sure it's sending what I expect.

Comment: @ilvar: Thanks a lot for your comments! 
Yes,  the caller service  store the document in  MongoDB before pushing to Elasticsearch. We clearly see couple of fields of the given document are not getting indexed in Elasticsearch in very few occasions. But the worse part is, the fields are very random. Hence it becomes very difficult to identify the pattern and perform RCA. Elasticsearch returns response as success. We observe the sequence number and version both are getting incremented. When we query the ES we do observe apart from couple fields, rest all the fields are getting updated properly.

Comment: Can you share the code where you provide document ID and body to the update query builder? Have you tried to use prepareIndex instead and reindex the document as a whole?